# IIS Domain rewrite to subfolder (only home page)

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I want my domain homepage to be redirected to one of my mvc directories

this is the rule i am using

```
<rule name="Home" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^/*$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/test/" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Same rule is working if i put redirect. But rewrite is not working.

Other URLS should be served normally. Only home page should be rewritten

Can we achieve this without ARR?

//www.example.com should be rewritten to //www.example.com/test/

www.example.com/buy should be served as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect. Correct rule is:

```
 <rule name="Home" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/test/" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
 </rule>
```

And this rule will work without ARR because you rewriting to a subfolder in the same website. If you want to rewrite to the different website in IIS, then you need ARR.